# Postman gives right response,but restassured returns empty for same request?

Tags: post, rest-assured

As you can see that postman returns expected result

[image: Expected result]

but res.asString() gives [] in the blow code,can you tell me why?

```
def "simple test"(){
    String url="http://xxx.xxx.xxx/assessment/api/Test.html"

    when:""
    io.restassured.response.Response res=RestAssured.given().header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").formParam("Action", "getDiagnosisList").formParam("Data", "[{\"subject\":\"冠心病\",\"option\":\"是\"}]").post(url)

    then:""
    res.prettyPrint()=="[\"身体健康状态不良\",\"医疗处置\"]"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that Chinese characters can't be encoded correctedly by default,after adding blow code,everything worked as expected:

```
 RestAssured.given().config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(EncoderConfig.encoderConfig().defaultContentCharset("UTF-8")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the request did via postman has not been cached, and on the other hand the same request via restassured is using some kind of cache. Recently I was having a similar issue because of it was hitting the varnish server. I'd recommend you to take a look at the response headers from both postman and restassured.

Comment: ,thanks,I tried multiple times from different machine in different time,each time postman gives me expected result,but RestAssured gives empty []